# MIPS errors and operation

Tags: mips

```
#if true perform matrix operation
mul.s $f7, $f5, $f6 #m * a[d][c]
add.s f7, $f7, $f5 #add (m*a[d][c])+col c

div.s $f5, $f4, $f2 #divide -a[r][d]/a[d][d] and store to m
move $f3, $zero #setting [r][d] = 0
```

I'm receiving errors on my `add.s` and `mov` register lines. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `$`-sign on the line `add.s f7, $f7, $f5`. It should be `add.s $f7, $f7, $f5`.

I don't know how your assembler handles `move` instructions with floating-point registers (or *if* it does), but I'd suggest using `mtc1 $zero,$f3` instead. Normally you'd follow that with a `cvt.s.w` or `cvt.d.w` to convert the value to floating point, but in the case of 0 that isn't necessary.